# How to hide or cut a Qwidget() text when I change main window size

Tags: python-2.7, qt4, pyqt4

**EDIT**: When I change the main window size, I need cut the text of `QLabel()` that includes in `QStatusBar()` to fit the size of the form. As shown in the diagram below.

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import * 
from PyQt4.QtCore import * 
import sys

class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow): 

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setCentralWidget(QLabel("main widget"))

        statusBar = QStatusBar()
        self.setStatusBar(statusBar)

        statusBar.addWidget(QLabel("first message"))
        statusBar.addWidget(QLabel("second message"))
        statusBar.addWidget(QLabel("a thrid long long long long long message"))

app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
window = MyMainWindow()    
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: simulation]

Comment: Try to add a layout that will wrap your content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to this is to set an appropriate minimum width on the labels, which will then allow them to resize smaller than the width of their text. However, this will simply crop the text on the right, rather eliding it (i.e. so that `...` appears at the end).

The blog post [Status bar and elided label](http://www.mimec.org/node/307) explains how to get elided text, but the solution is written in C++. Below is an equivalent version written in PyQt4:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class ElidedLabel(QtGui.QLabel):
    _width = _text = _elided = None

    def __init__(self, text='', width=40, parent=None):
        super(ElidedLabel, self).__init__(text, parent)
        self.setMinimumWidth(width if width > 0 else 1)

    def elidedText(self):
        return self._elided or ''

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        self.drawFrame(painter)
        margin = self.margin()
        rect = self.contentsRect()
        rect.adjust(margin, margin, -margin, -margin)
        text = self.text()
        width = rect.width()
        if text != self._text or width != self._width:
            self._text = text
            self._width = width
            self._elided = self.fontMetrics().elidedText(
                text, QtCore.Qt.ElideRight, width)
        option = QtGui.QStyleOption()
        option.initFrom(self)
        self.style().drawItemText(
            painter, rect, self.alignment(), option.palette,
            self.isEnabled(), self._elided, self.foregroundRole())

class MyMainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QtGui.QMainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setCentralWidget(QtGui.QLabel("main widget"))

        statusBar = QtGui.QStatusBar()
        self.setStatusBar(statusBar)

        statusBar.addWidget(ElidedLabel("first message"))
        statusBar.addWidget(ElidedLabel("second message"))
        statusBar.addWidget(ElidedLabel("a third long long long long long message"))

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MyMainWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I am impressed. It's a fantastic solution and very elaborate. Thank you for spend your time.